# Typescript Shorthand ambient modules

Tags: typescript

Here is the piece of code from [official guide about module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

```
import x, {y} from "hot-new-module";
x(y);
```

I don't understand the syntax. Why x is not in the curly bracket? What is the syntax?

Answer (score 3):

`x` is the default export. `y` is a named export.

Module.ts

```
export class y { }
const x = (someVar: y) => { /* */ };
export default x;
```

This is imported with your syntax

```
import x, {y} from "hot-new-module";
x(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble understanding that part of the handbook too, but eventually I figured it out. What they meant is that you can have a declaration file that contains only `declare module "mymodulename";` and then you can import anything from that module even though you did not declare anything.
That's why anything you import will have the ***any*** type. example:

*shorthandmodule.d.ts*

```
declare module "hot-new-module";
```

*myscript.ts*

```
import blabla, {x}, {anything} from "hot-new-module"
```

**blabla**, **x** and **anything** are of type ***any*** that's why you can type things like

```
blabla(x)
x(blabla)
anything[x]
anything.unknownproperty = true
```

The lack of curly brackets around **blabla** implies it refers to a `default export` in the module. There can be only 1 default export per module, that's why only the blabla has no brackets, but It could be any of the imports, since none of them were declared anyway.

Comment: Could you tell where should I put this shorthandmodule.d.ts? should I import it?